# How to get html of a page loaded in QWebEngineView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I am trying to get HTML of a page loaded in PyQT5 QWebEngineView. Here is a simple example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def callback_function(html):
    print(html)


def on_load_finished():

    web.page().runJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]", callback_function)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com"))
web.show()
web.loadFinished.connect(on_load_finished)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I was hoping to be able to return html from the runJavaScript() call but i get a blank in the callback function.

What is incorrect in my code and what alternatives are available for obtaining HTML of a page?

Comment: Alternatives? probably using PySide2. Your code works out of the box by just changing the import

Comment: @Pa_ could you share a link to an example?

Comment: @Pa_ PySide2 is not an option, for example it does not have many functions implemented, IMHO PyQt5 has fewer bugs than PySide2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351643/how-to-save-dynamically-generated-web-page-in-qwebengineview/57352932#57352932) written C++ and translating the solution to Python:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


def callback_function(html):
    print(html)


def on_load_finished():
    web.page().runJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML", callback_function)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com"))
web.show()
web.resize(640, 480)
web.loadFinished.connect(on_load_finished)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update:**

The problem in your case is that getElementsByTagName() returns a list of js elements, and that element cannot be exported to python, what you should do is get the innerHTML:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


def callback_function(html):
    print(html)


def on_load_finished():
    web.page().runJavaScript(
        "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML", callback_function
    )
    # or document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com"))
web.show()
web.resize(640, 480)
web.loadFinished.connect(on_load_finished)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is there a way without a callback function but accessing raw html?